# How is OneDrive used space calculated

Tags: disk-space, onedrive

My (personal) OneDrive account shows that I have used 359 MB out of 5 GB, but the synced folder on my home pc only uses 67 MB. This is roughly the same size as all folder sizes on OneDrive combined. Which makes sense, since I have no 'online only' files.

The trash folder on OneDrive is empty, so what am I missing?

[image: OneDrive screenshot]

Comment: is the complete onedrive synced? onedrive always selective syncing so not all data are downloaded.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes, as I said, there are *no* 'online-only' files.